# Make multiple shiny apps use same RData and csv files on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

I have a single app that needs to be reproduced 70 times for each of my clients. The app for all 70 of my clients uses the same csv files and global environment. I currently have a shiny app project that has a structure similar to this:

```
PeakAnalysis
     -data
          -data1.csv
          -data2.csv
          -data3.csv
          -data4.csv
          -peakAnalysisAll.RData
     -packrat
     -PeakAnalysis.Rproj
     -client1
          -rsconnect
          -server.R
          -ui.R
     -client2
          -rsconnect
          -server.R
          -ui.R
     -etc.
```

Is there a way that I can publish these apps so that they all use the RData and csv files from my data folder in my project?